# Error tells me I need JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to get the source code from a website with `urllib` in Python 3. When I run my script, I'm told that I need JavaScript enabled in my browser. However, I'm quite certain that it is enabled. Here are my script and errors:

[image]

Error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
>   "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py"
>   --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 57883 --file /Users/titusflex/PycharmProjects/HelloPython/testtest.py warning:
>   Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run
>   '"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5"
>   "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py"
>   build_ext --inplace' to build. pydev debugger: process 3089 is
>   connecting
>
> Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.598)
>   b"http://www.google.com/adwords/select/interstitial_short_js.html'>var jsRedirect = true;var
>   url =
>   '\/um\/identity?authuser\x3d0\x26dst\x3d\/cm\/CampaignMgmt?';if
>   (self.document.location.hash) {var querySeparator = (url.indexOf('?')
>   == -1) ? '?' : '&'; url += querySeparator + 'frag=' + encodeURIComponent(self.document.location.hash.substring(1));}window.location.assign(url);"
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: So the resulting HTML which you download contains Javascript? Well, Python won't interpret that for you, it just gives you the raw downloaded HTML source code. If you're not a browser and you're not otherwise running the Javascript, that's all you get.

Comment: Your ‘browser’ in this case is Python. I really don't think you've got JavaScript there.

Comment: That does not appear to be a Python error message. Where do you see the error? It sounds like its in the downloaded page content and related to the fact the page contains JS detection code.  If the page requires JS to operate as you expect when you view it in a browser you need a headless browser to do the same.

Comment: What does your browser have to do with this? You're downloading the code in Python.

Comment: I just want to get the data on the site.. :(

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a complete beginner

Comment: What is printed by `print(respData)`?

Comment: print(respData) prints <head><noscript><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=http://www.google.com/adwords/select/interstitial_short_js.html'></noscript></head><body><script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>var jsRedirect = true;var url = '\\/um\\/identity?authuser\\x3d0\\x26dst\\x3d\\/cm\\/CampaignMgmt?';if (self.document.location.hash) {var querySeparator = (url.indexOf('?') == -1) ? '?' : '&'; url += querySeparator + 'frag=' + encodeURIComponent(self.document.location.hash.substring(1));}window.location.assign(url);</script></body></html>"

Process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually getting the response from the site but the site's server has its own way of responding when it receives a request from a client, which it thinks has no javascript support.

So, you need to look for ways to spoof your scraping call to the site to make it look like you can handle Javascript.

You can try to fake the user-agent request header but I seriously doubt that would work.  You will be better off with something like Selenium.

**Edit**

- http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/
- https://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/